# How to verify individually if some files exist inside a batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with a batch. I want that the batch verify individually if some files exist in the specific path.
The problem in the code is that the first "if exist..." runs ok but the second "if exist" doesn't run, make a rapid error and closing cmd. The error that appear is " it doesn't expect \Novell\Zenworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe in this moment".
The code which has the problem is:

```
@echo off
if exist "c:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\esm\ZESUser.exe" (
    echo El archivo ZESUser.exe EXISTE
    echo El archivo ZESUser EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log
    tasklist | find "ZESUser.exe" || start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Novell\ZENworks\esm\ZESUser.exe
    tasklist | find "ZESUser.exe" && echo ZESUser.exe en EJECUCION
) else (
    echo El archivo ZESUser.exe NO EXISTE
    echo El archivo ZESUser.exe NO EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log
)

if exist "c:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe" (
    echo El archivo ZenUserDaemon.exe EXISTE
    echo El archivo ZenUserDaemon.exe EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log
    tasklist | find "ZenUserDaemon.exe" || start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe
    tasklist | find "ZenUserDaemon.exe" && echo ZenUserDaemon.exe en EJECUCION
) else (
    echo El archivo ZenUserDaemon.exe NO EXISTE
    echo El archivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe NO EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log  
)
```

I was trying to modify the code for discover where the problem was and I discover that this code runs both " if exist", but I don't understand why when I insert "tasklist...." lines it doesn't run at first code.

The code that run is:

```
@echo off
if exist "c:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\esm\ZESUser.exe" (
    echo El archivo ZESUser.exe EXISTE >> c:\soft\zenworks.log
    echo El archivo ZESUser.exe EXISTE      
) else (
 echo El archivo ZESUser.exe NO EXISTE >> c:\soft\zenworks.log
 echo El archivo ZESUser.exe NO EXISTE        
)
if exist "c:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe" (
    echo El archivo ZenUserDaemon.exe EXISTE >> c:\soft\zenworks.log
    echo El archivo ZenUserDaemon.exe EXISTE        
) else (
    echo El archivo ZenUserDaemon.exe NO EXISTE >> c:\soft\zenworks.log
    echo El archivo ZenUserDaemon.exe NO EXISTE
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start your program in a command prompt AND READ THE ERROR.

Comment: You are not using the `START` command correctly.  Read the help file for that command.

Comment: It may also be noteworthy that your `Find` command is currently case sensitive. Are you certain that those executables use that specific mixed case?

Comment: The executables are written as they should be, I have executed the code only by executing the first if exist and all the code works correctly (both the start command and find and tasklist).
The problem appears when running the second if exist consecutive to the first one. I ran the code line by line.

Comment: If the first "if exist" runs correctly because with the second one it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In your topmost code example the closing parenthesis on `x86)` would prematurely end the opening parenthesis  from your `else (` condition. It should therefore be escaped with the caret **`^`**.

```bat
echo El archivo C:\Program Files (x86^)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe NO EXISTE>> C:\Soft\zenworks.log
```

Here's a rewritten example for you to improve your coding style:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "ZU=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Novell\ZENworks\esm\ZESUser.exe"
Set "ZUD=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe"
Set "Log=C:\Soft\zenworks.log"

For %%A In ("%ZU%" "%ZUD%") Do (If Exist %%A (Echo El archivo %%~nxA EXISTE
        Echo El archivo %%~nxA EXISTE>>"%Log%"
        TaskList | Find /I "%%~nxA" >Nul && (Echo %%~nxA en EJECUCION
        ) || Start "" %%A) Else (Echo El archivo %%~nxA NO EXISTE
        Echo El archivo %%~nxA NO EXISTE>>"%Log%"))

Pause
```

Please read the help for the `Find` and`Start` commands for usage information: `Find /?` and `Start /?`. Additionally you can take a look at `Set /?` and `For /?` too.

Comment: I really appreciate the code and I've tried it but I still don't understand why two "if exist..." do not work in a row. If the first "if exist..." runs, ok, why doesn't the second one?.If there is a problem with the syntax of the find or start command, it will not work in both "if exist...".

Comment: If you have used my code complete as written and the file doesn't show as existing, then the likelihood is that it doesn't exist. Are you certain that it resides in that directory and not in `"%ProgramFiles%\Novell\ZENworks\bin"`? If you are, then to ensure you haven't somehow undefined the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` system variable, replace it in the first two lines with `C:\Program Files (x86)`. If that doesn't work, try entering the following at your Command prompt and post the results exactly as they are returned, `Where /F *ZenUserDaemon*`

Comment: Thanks Compo, the problem was in the last line: echo El archivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe NO EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log

Comment: Thanks Compo, the problem was in the last line, where it appears: echo El archivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe NO EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log   - It should be: echo El archivo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe" NO EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log -The code already works

Comment: Absolutely not! In my provided code, which I created to match your `The code that run is:` statement my answer does not output the full path, it uses `%%~nxA` which outputs only the filename with extension. Had you wanted the full path, you'd simply change `%%~nxA` to `%%A` which is already doublequoted.

Answer (score 0):

I've debugged the code and the problem was on the last line.

```
echo El archivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe NO EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log
```

The path syntax was misspelled in the echo command of the second "if exist... else". I should have written:

```
echo El archivo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin\ZenUserDaemon.exe" NO EXISTE >> C:\Soft\zenworks.log
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Of course that would be an issue, which you'd have clearly seen with the provided error message had you followed the advice provided to you in the first comment by ACatInLove. That particular echo line required to be quoted or the include an escape character, because the closing parenthesis on `x86)` would prematurely end the opening parenthesis  from your `else (` condition. You could therefore have simply used the following which I have now included by editing my answer.